# Error al compilar passing const

Tags: c++, loops

hay un error que no para de salirme  al compilar y no lo entiendo, les explico, yo pretendo hacer la potencia de un lenguaje, ej dado un lenguaje L {0,1}, hacer L^2, eso nos daria {00,01,10,11}.

eso es lo que pretendo hacer en mi codigo, sin embargo, sale el siguiente y

```
passing 'const std::basic_string<char>' as 'this' argument of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

refiriendose a  la linea  de mi codigo:

```
(*it1)=iter;
```

Este es el codigo:

```
void operaciones::potencia(int exponente){
    set<string>::iterator it1;
    set<string> result;
    char it2;
    char it3;
    int i;
    int j;
    int contador=0;
    while(contador<exponente){

        for(it1=lenguaje.begin(); it1!=lenguaje.end(); it1++){
            for(i=(*it1)[i]; i<(*it1).size();i++){
                for(j=(*it1)[j]; j<(*it1).size();j++){
                    char k=(*it1)[j];
                    string iter=(*it1);
                    iter.push_back(k);
                    (*it1)=iter;
                }
                result.insert((*it1));
            }

        }
        contador++;
    }
    write(result,cout);


}
```

Constructores de la clase

```
operaciones::operaciones(const string cadena){
        string h; //si, solo se usa en esta funcion, se declara en esta funcion
        int i=0; //en set son desde 0
        //en un lenguaje no puede haber dos cadenas repetidas, es redundante tener mas de una
        int longitud=cadena.length();

        // un while de entrada no sirve porque si encuentra una coma no vuelve  a entrar 

        for (int i=0; i<longitud;i++){ //es caracter por caracter

            while(cadena[i]!='{' && cadena[i]!= ',' && cadena[i]!= '}' && i<longitud){ //las comparaciones con comilla simple, caracteres con comilla simple, string con una doble!!! 
                h.push_back(cadena[i]);
                i++;
            }
            if (cadena[i]==',' || cadena[i]=='}' ){

                lenguaje.insert(h); //contenido de string
                h.clear();
            }


        }


    }

    operaciones::operaciones(const operaciones& lenguaje3){//constructor de copia
        lenguaje=lenguaje3.lenguaje;//accediendo atributo lenguaje3
    }
```

De verdad,os agradezco que me expliquen donde ven el fallo y cómo corregirlo

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una cosa que no entiendo: ¿ qué pretendes conseguir con esto ?

```
result.insert((*it1))
```

Guardas la cadena sin modificar en tu `result`. ¿ No deberías hacer

```
result.insert( iter );
```

Ahora, al *tema*:

Hay un *detallito* sobre los contenedores `set` que se te ha escapado: una vez introducido un valor en ellos, **no se puede modificar**.

La explicación es muy sencilla: internamente, esos contenedores tienen una cierta estructura interna, solo conocida por ellos. Normalmente, se implementan con un *árbol*, para permitir realizar búsquedas *binarias* de forma rápida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa imagen, imagina que tienes un *iterador* que apunta al elemento `6`, y tú lo cambias por un `15`. ¿ Que pasará ?

Que el *árbol* **se rompe**. Su estructura interna deja de ser válida, y cualquier intento de *buscar* algún dato será un *comportamiento indefinido*; lo mas probable es que el programa se bloquee, o intente acceder a memoria que no le pertenece, o *valla usted a saber*.

Por eso, los *iteradores* proporcionados por un `set` **no permiten modificar el dato al que apuntan**; se comportan, a todos los efectos, como si fueran `const_iterator` (en realidad, es **el dato** lo que es `const`).

Eso es lo que te está diciendo el mensaje: `*iter` apunta a una `const string`, y esta última **no soporta el `operator=`**. Es una `string` **de solo lectura**.

La solución es **crear un nuevo `set`** e ir almacenando en el los elementos modificados; cosa que tú **ya haces** en `result`. Al final de la función, basta con asignar tu `result` a tu `lenguaje`.

```
void operaciones::potencia(int exponente){
  set<string>::iterator it1;
  set<string> result;
  char it2;
  char it3;
  int i;
  int j;
  int contador=0;

  while(contador<exponente){    
    for(it1=lenguaje.begin(); it1!=lenguaje.end(); it1++){
      for(i=(*it1)[i]; i<(*it1).size();i++){
         for(j=(*it1)[j]; j<(*it1).size();j++){
            char k=(*it1)[j];
            string iter=(*it1);
            iter.push_back(k);

            // (*it1)=iter;
          }
        result.insert(iter); // <- ¿¿ no será esto lo que quieres ??
      }  
    }
    contador++;
  }
  lenguaje = result; // <- Añadimos esto
  write(result,cout);
}
```

Si mis suposiciones sobre lo que intentas son correctas, con eso debería de bastar.

Comment: @ Hola, gracias por la ayuda,me muestra el resultdo mal, o sea, para {0,1} al cuadrado, me sale {,00,11,}

Comment: @AER jeje ... eso ya es otra pregunta, ¿ no ? Ahora cuando pueda te lo miro, que estoy *liaillo* en este momento ...

Comment: @AER A ver si lo pillo. ¿ Quieres todas las permutaciones posibles de los dígitos binarios contenidos en una cadena ?

Comment: exacto , me di cuenta de eso, necesitaría otro for mas no?

Comment: para hacer las permutaciones

Comment: @AER No puedes resolverlo así si esperas que funcione con un número variable de dígitos. Para 2 dígitos, son 2 `for`. Para 3 dígitos, son 3 `for`. Para 4 dígitos ... estoy estudiando otra forma. Te aviso.

Comment: Hola, ya encontraste el fallo en mi planteamiento? yo no he dado con otra idea

Comment: @AER yo he estado haciendolo sobre otra base. Es *complejillo* de explicar. ¿ [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66702/charla-con-aer) ?